# I need to output my Access table to a website using PHP

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, html-table, odbc

Alright, I have no problem outputting multiple lines of data out of the database, I just have no idea how to get it out in the format I want.

Here's my basic issue.

```
<tr>
    <?php               
    //make connection to database, bail if no connection
    $connection = odbc_pconnect('sitedata','','');
    if (!$connection) { exit("Connection Failed: " . $connection); }

    //retrieve relevant data
    $Date = "SELECT EntryDate AS DT FROM TimeSheet WHERE EmployeeID = 'AA01'";

    $rs = odbc_exec($connection, $Date);

    //output data
    while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
        $Line1 = odbc_result($rs, 'DT');
        printf("<td><center>%s</center></td>", $Line1);                 
    }
    ?>
</tr>
```

What this will do is output a one row table, with each new date creating a new column.

Now then, this is sort of useless to me as these need to be output into a single column, where each new datavalue is the beginning of a row. After this, I need to expand the table width wise, adding new data values such as:

```
$Time = "SELECT TotalTime as EN FROM TimeSheet WHERE EmployeeID = 'AA01'";
$JobName = "SELECT JobName as JN FROM TimeSheet WHERE EmployeeID = 'AA01'";
```

Where Time is it's own column, JobName is it's own column, etc.

How exactly do I do this? There obviously must be a way, I'm just new at this. Any help is greatly, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the fields in one SQL statement...

```
SELECT EntryDate AS DT, TotalTime as EN, JobName as JN 
    FROM TimeSheet WHERE EmployeeID = 'AA01';
```

With that you can do exactly what you are doing now except build a full row instead of columns.

```
<?php               
    //make connection to database, bail if no connection
    $connection = odbc_pconnect('sitedata','','');
    if (!$connection) { exit("Connection Failed: " . $connection); }

    //retrieve relevant data
    $Date = "SELECT EntryDate AS DT, TotalTime as EN, JobName as JN FROM TimeSheet WHERE EmployeeID = 'AA01';";

    $rs = odbc_exec($connection, $Date);

    //output data
    while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
        $DT = odbc_result($rs, 'DT');
        $EN = odbc_result($rs, 'EN');
        $JN = odbc_result($rs, 'JN');

        printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $DT, $EN, $JN);                 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Been struggling with this for quite a while.